# take last 4th digit and round to three digits of whole number in ms access

Tags: ms-access

How to replace the last digit with 0 and round the digit to the left up or down. So I have a long list of access numbers like 1542, 1475, 1680. I would like to round these so the would read 1540, 1480, and 1680. I tried using the round function but that doesn't work with whole numbers. Are there any built-in functions using the control source to display these numbers like this or does it have to be a VBA function?

Answer (score 1):

You can divide by 10, then round to 0 decimals, then multiply by 10.

```
UPDATE bar
SET foo = CLng(Round(foo/10, 0) * 10)
```

If you don't like the "Bankers rounding" that Access does, check out http://www.allenbrowne.com/round.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any built-in function for this but maybe this will work:

```
Dim x as Long
x = Round((1542/10) + 0.01) * 10
```

What this does is:

1. Temporarily make the value into a number with one decimal digit by
   sort of right shifting it one digit past the decimal point;
2. Use the Round function to round this intermediate decimal value;
3. Slap trailing zero on the end.

When I tested this in an Immediate Window, it turns out that numbers ending in "5" are rounded down and you want them rounded up. To fix this, you need to add 0.01 before rounding so that numbers ending in "5" get a little bigger and so are rounded up.

I know it's not exactly what you may have been looking for but it is still one-line of VBA.

Answer (score 1):

The *Round* function is severely bugged.

From my project [VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round), use the *RoundMid* function, which correctly rounds any value:

```
RoundedBy10 = RoundMid(Value, -1)

1475 -> 1480 
1542 -> 1540 
1680 -> 1680
```

The function:

```vb
' Rounds Value by 4/5 with count of decimals as specified with parameter NumDigitsAfterDecimal.
'
' Rounds to integer if NumDigitsAfterDecimal is zero.
'
' Rounds correctly Value until max/min value limited by a Scaling of 10
' raised to the power of (the number of decimals).
'
' Uses CDec() to prevent bit errors of reals.
'
' Execution time is about 1µs.
'
' 2018-02-09. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function RoundMid( _
    ByVal Value As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal NumDigitsAfterDecimal As Long, _
    Optional ByVal MidwayRoundingToEven As Boolean) _
    As Variant

    Dim Scaling     As Variant
    Dim Half        As Variant
    Dim ScaledValue As Variant
    Dim ReturnValue As Variant
    
    ' Only round if Value is numeric and ReturnValue can be different from zero.
    If Not IsNumeric(Value) Then
        ' Nothing to do.
        ReturnValue = Null
    ElseIf Value = 0 Then
        ' Nothing to round.
        ' Return Value as is.
        ReturnValue = Value
    Else
        Scaling = CDec(Base10 ^ NumDigitsAfterDecimal)
        
        If Scaling = 0 Then
            ' A very large value for NumDigitsAfterDecimal has minimized scaling.
            ' Return Value as is.
            ReturnValue = Value
        ElseIf MidwayRoundingToEven Then
            ' Banker's rounding.
            If Scaling = 1 Then
                ReturnValue = Round(Value)
            Else
                ' First try with conversion to Decimal to avoid bit errors for some reals like 32.675.
                ' Very large values for NumDigitsAfterDecimal can cause an out-of-range error when dividing.
                On Error Resume Next
                ScaledValue = Round(CDec(Value) * Scaling)
                ReturnValue = ScaledValue / Scaling
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    ' Decimal overflow.
                    ' Round Value without conversion to Decimal.
                    ReturnValue = Round(Value * Scaling) / Scaling
                End If
            End If
        Else
            ' Standard 4/5 rounding.
            ' Very large values for NumDigitsAfterDecimal can cause an out-of-range error when dividing.
            On Error Resume Next
            Half = CDec(0.5)
            If Value > 0 Then
                ScaledValue = Int(CDec(Value) * Scaling + Half)
            Else
                ScaledValue = -Int(-CDec(Value) * Scaling + Half)
            End If
            ReturnValue = ScaledValue / Scaling
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                ' Decimal overflow.
                ' Round Value without conversion to Decimal.
                Half = CDbl(0.5)
                If Value > 0 Then
                    ScaledValue = Int(Value * Scaling + Half)
                Else
                    ScaledValue = -Int(-Value * Scaling + Half)
                End If
                ReturnValue = ScaledValue / Scaling
            End If
        End If
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            ' Rounding failed because values are near one of the boundaries of type Double.
            ' Return value as is.
            ReturnValue = Value
        End If
    End If
    
    RoundMid = ReturnValue

End Function
```